# Jerky jQuery cased by iframe loadings

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jquery-animate

I'm doing a website, at the beginning I must start some http requests setting some iframe sources, to partially disguise this loading I've inserted at the beginning an intro animation created by jQuery, in this way at the end of it the requests are finished (or almost).

The problem is that, cause the iframes loadings, the animation is so jerky... Is there some solution?

Comment: Using iframe, AFAIK there is no solution. Your best bet would be to not use iframes. Is it cross domain iframes? Just as a side note, using CSS animation should be less jerky but still...

Comment: no, it isn't cross domain iframe, but I need to use iframe because I'm working just on the front end, the system work on ASP.NET and the back end programmer need of the viewstate(and I think is not possibile to use it using div instead of iframe)...